# Prove that $\{\cos(nx) : n=1, ... ,\infty \}$ is bounded but not totally bounded in $C([0,\pi])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that $\{f = \cos(nx) : n=1, ... ,\infty \}$ is a bounded subset (of functions), but not totally bounded, of $C([0, \pi])$ under the supremum norm (or uniform norm, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm).

Note that a totally bounded set has a convergent subsequence in a complete metric space.

Comment: Well it is clearly bounded since $\cos(\mathbb R)=[-1,1]$.

Comment: @DonThousand The question is about a set of functions $x\mapsto \cos(nx),$ not about the numbers $\cos(nx)$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: Yes, @NikhilSahoo is correct.

Comment: @U.Hill He's not correct in the sense that $\cos(nx)$ is a wrong notation to refer to a function.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I changed the question, hopefully is more clear.

Comment: @U.Hill Now it's easier to guess what you mean, but still not correct. It should be $\{x\mapsto \cos(nx)\ldots\}$. Sometimes you can avoid $x\mapsto$ by replacing the variable by a dot, as in $\cos(n\cdot)$, but it needs to be clear from context.

Comment: Um... isn't it obvious.  By definition $||\cos nx||_\infty = \sup \{\cos nx|x\in \mathbb R\}$ and that is clearly $1$.  So for any $\cos nx, \cos mx\in $ your set  $|| \cos nx - \cos mx|| \le 2$.   .... Am I misunderstanding something?.... Edit:  Oh, I missed the "not totally bounded"  I guess that is the less trivial aspect.  Never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $S = \{x \mapsto \cos(nx) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is clearly bounded since 
$$\|\cos(mx) - \cos(nx)\|_\infty \le \|\cos(mx)\|_\infty + \|\cos(nx)\|_\infty = 2$$

To show that $S$ is not totally bounded, notice that $S$ is an orthogonal set of functions in the inner product space $(C([0,\pi]), \|\cdot\|_2)$ w.r.t. to the the standard inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^\pi f\overline{g}$.

In particular, $S$ is a discrete infinite set in $(C([0,\pi]), \|\cdot\|_2)$ and hence it cannot be totally bounded.

If $S$ were totally bounded in $(C([0,\pi]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there would exist $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in S$ and $r_1, \ldots, r_n > 0$ such that $$S \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_\infty(f_i, r_i).$$

Since $\|\cdot\|_2 \le \pi\|\cdot\|_\infty$, we would have
$$S \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_\infty(f_i, r_i) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_2(f_i, \pi r_i)$$

which would imply that $S$ is totally bounded in $(C([0,\pi]), \|\cdot\|_2)$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For fixed $m,$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^\pi (\cos (mx)-\cos (nx))^2\,dx = \pi.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I am working with the uniform norm. @zhw.

Comment: @U.Hill The inclusion $I:(C[0,\pi], ||\cdot||_{\infty} ) \to (C[0,\pi], ||\cdot||_{2} )$ is a continuous mapping.

Comment: Umm... I am mainly focused on the "not totally bounded" part

Comment: @U.Hill Right, so if you have a convergent subsequence with the sup norm then it must map to a convergent subsequence in $L_2$, but zhw answer indicates that any subsequence of $\cos n x$ cannot be convergent is $L_2$ since it cannot my Cauchy

Comment: @clark That is a very helpful explanation, thank you so much.