# Is the set $\{f = \cos(nx) : n=1, ... ,\infty \}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I guess the set $\{f = \cos(nx) : n=1, ... ,\infty\}$ is closed in $\ C([0,1])$ under the sup norm. Therefore, I am trying to show its limit function is of the form $\cos(nx)$. However, I have difficulty proving that for $\cos(n_ix)$ to converge, $\ n_i$ must be constant after some term. At first, I tried to prove c $\leq$ $\mid cos(nx)-cos(mx)\mid$ for some positive c and distinct m and n. 
Is my guess wrong?

Comment: Yes. This same problem was asked recently. Maybe the other version already has answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\{\cos(nx) : n=1, ... ,\infty \}$ is a bounded subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466039/prove-that-cosnx-n-1-infty-is-a-bounded-subset)

Comment: @conditionalMethod That question is asking whether the family of functions $x\mapsto \cos nx$ is *uniformly bounded*, not whether it is *closed*.

Comment: @Math1000 One follows from the other.

Comment: I don't see how. It was shown that these functions are uniformly bounded, but I don't see how they can be closed considering there is no limit function.

Comment: @Math1000 That's not the only thing proven there, nor what was about most the the argument about. ... $\{1,2,3,...\}$ is closed and there is no limit besides the eventually constant sequences.

Comment: Ah, good point. I suppose it does not make sense to argue that a set is not closed if does not contain its limit, if it does not have any limit points to begin with. I concede.

Comment: Does the domain [0,1] have no effect on the result? It seems that under the domain, they are not orthogonal.

Answer (score 3):

The set is closed. If not we would come to contradiction in the following way:

Denote $f_n(x)=cos(nx)$ and assume that some subsequence of $f_n$ converges to $f$ in sense of supremum norm and $f$ is not from the set. Let denote this subsequence as $f_k$.

Let $t\in [0,1]$. we see that $$|\int_0^tf_k-f\;dx|\leq \|f_{k}-f\|_\infty\to 0\mbox{ as }k\to\infty.$$

We see that $\int_0^tf_k\;dx=-sin(kt)/k\to 0$. Hence $\int_0^tf\;dx=0$ for every $t$ and so $f=0$.  But $1=\|f_{k}\|_\infty\to \|f\|_\infty$ and so $\|f\|_\infty=1$ what is a contradiction.

Comment: The method is great. I didn't notice we can construct a sequence with increasing k such that fk goes to f  if f fails to fall into the set.

Comment: This is the method of computing weak limits in $L^p$ spaces. It is usefull until you are able to compute the integral on interval $[0,t]$.